# how to write Lex and yacc code for a BNF Grammar

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, yacc, lex

I am a beginner started off with learning lex and yacc, I have BNF grammar as given below:
    Could someone suggest to me how to write Lex and yacc when given a BNF grammar given below

```
For example, if I want to write nested statements using (this that) using lex and yacc how can i 
do that
Note: this that is same as if else

<language>::=<code>
<code>::=<statement><code>
<program>::=begin<statement_list>end
<statement_list>=<statement>;|<statement>;<statement_list>
<statement>::=loop <var> := <var> step <var> until<var> do
<statement>::= this <cond><statement>
<statement>::=this<cond><statement> that<statement>
<statement>::=write(<string>)|write(<expr>)
<statement>::=comment <string>
<cond>::=<val> == <val>
<cond> ::= <val> > <val>
<cond> ::= <val> < <val> 
<cond> ::= <val> >= <val> 
<cond> ::= <val> <= <val> 
<statement>::=<var>:=<expr> 
<expr>::=<val> + <val>| <val> * <val>| <val> - <val>|<val> / <val>|<val>
<val>::=<var>
<val> ::= <num>
<string>::="<text>"
<num> ::= <dig> | <dig><num> 
<text> ::= <dig> | <char> | <text><text> 
<val>::=A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z|
a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j | k | l | m | n | o | p | q | r | s | t | u | v | w | x | 
y | z
<dig> :: = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
```

Comment: Start by reading the documentation on lex and yacc.  When you have a specific question, come back.  No, I'm not the downvoter but I understand his sentiment.

Comment: Why are you using BNF? It's been obsolete for nearly 50 years. The syntax used by `yacc` is preferred nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

The input syntax of yacc is basically a BNF variant, and you can feed it directly with characters.  So replace the single character tokens with character literals, replace the <name>s with identifiers, and replace ::= with just : and you pretty much have a yacc grammar, though not an unambiguous one, so it won't work properly without further work to deal with the ambiguities.

It will be more efficient to move some of the rules into lex, and the grammar above has incomplete assumptions about whitespace that need to be dealt with, but if you start with any basic tutorial about lex&yacc ([there are many of them](https://www.google.com/search?q=lex+%26+yacc&oq=lex+%26+yacc)) it reasonably straight forward.